# Failed to parse a file

Tags: android

Hi I have an app which uses android 2.1 and it runs fine on the emulator, when I try installing the apk, I get the error, 'failed to parse the file' i just copied the apk from the bin directory to my phone..
Any idea why this error is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the signing and apk generation tool to generate the apk file? Also, are you sure the phone supports Android 2.1?

Comment: I haven't done the first one..i just copied the apk from the directory/bin.. Yes i am sure the phone supports android 2.1

Comment: I also did sign in ut of no avail

Answer (score 0):

in settings -> application-> enable "unknown sources".